# Can´t import SCSS variables into another SCSS file

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I am trying to import a SCSS file which contains variables into another SCSS file, using the '@use' word. Other files which does not contain variables are well imported. It is just the file which contains variables.
Here is my '_variables.scss' file:

```
$soft-color: #e1e8f0;
$text-hero: white;
$text-white: white;
$card-color: #162c5b;
$button-color: white;
$button-text-color: black;
$features-color: #5ccaa7;
$technology-color: #038aff;
$awards-color: #038aff;
$easy-color: #febd3d;

$small-font: 0.8rem;

// Typography

//New variables
$ff-text: "Inter", sans-serif;
$fw-400: 400;
$fw-500: 500;
$fw-600: 600;
$fw-700: 700;
$box-shadow: rgba(35, 24, 54, 0.25);

/*.   Mixins.   */

@mixin shadow {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #e8ebf2;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 1px 4px;
}

/*    Functions    */

@function color($elem, $variant) {
  @return map-get(map-get($color, $elem), $variant);
}

/*    Variables   */

$color: (
  text: (
    1: #162c5b,
    2: #565678,
    3: #ababc9,
    soft: #718097,
    footer: #acaabf,
    1i: #fff,
    2i: rgba(#fff, 0.4),
  ),
  bg: (
    hero: #038aff,
    awards: #fafbff,
    3: #d2daf0,
    infinite: #161348,
    footer: #161348,
    line-footer: #2f2c5b,
    white: #fff,
  ),
);
```

And this is the main SCSS file which uses some of the variables that I am trying to import:

```
@use "header";
@use "layout";
@use "variables";


/*  Hero section  */
.hero {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: color(bg, hero);
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -70px; /* Keep a fixed pixel value */
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 10;
    background: linear-gradient(
      to right bottom,
      color(bg, hero) 50%,
      transparent 50%
    );
  }
  .container {
    width: min(1140px, 100%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    .flexbox {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 700px;
      .box {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 1rem;
        &:nth-child(2) {
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .trust {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          align-items: center;
          .logos {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            .logo {
              width: 110px;
              padding: 0 10px;
            }
          }
        }

        .card-wrapper {
          width: 440px;
          height: 560px;
          padding: 28px;
          background-color: white;
          border-radius: 16px 16px 80px 20px;
          .card-info {
            .top-info {
              display: flex;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
              justify-content: space-between;
              align-items: center;
              padding: 0 0 20px 0;
              .addnew {
                font-size: small;
                padding: 4px 8px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                border: 1px solid color(text, soft);
              }
              h3 {
                color: color(text, 1);
              }
              a {
                color: color(text, 1);
              }
            }
            .content {
              width: 100%;
              .box {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid $soft-color;
                .place {
                  h3 {
                    color: color(text, 1);
                    padding-bottom: 6px;
                  }
                  p {
                    color: color(text, soft);
                    font-size: small;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            .card-image {
              position: relative;
              overflow: hidden;
              width: 100%;
              height: 250px;
              padding: 24px;
              border-radius: 12px;
              background-color: $card-color;
              box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
              &::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: -130px;
                width: 400px;
                min-height: 300px;
                background-image: url("../img/world_map.svg");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                z-index: 0;
              }
              .info {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 10;
                .number {
                  h3 {
                    font-size: 0.7rem;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    padding-bottom: 10px;
                  }
                  h2 {
                    font-size: 1.5rem;
                  }
                }
                .details {
                  width: 100%;
                  .flex {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    div {
                      flex: 1;
                      h3 {
                        color: $text-white;
                        font-size: 0.7rem;
                        padding-bottom: 6px;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                      }
                      h4 {
                        color: $text-white;
                        font-size: 0.95rem;
                        font-weight: $fw-400;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              .iconbar {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 10;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding-bottom: 30px;
                .mastercard {
                  width: 40px;
                }
                .active {
                  padding: 6px 8px;
                  border-radius: 4px;
                  background-color: #79c7a9;
                  p {
                    color: $text-hero;
                    font-size: 0.8rem;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        .barra {
          width: 100%;
          padding-bottom: 30px;
          .button {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 14px 18px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            color: $button-text-color;
            background-color: $button-color;
            i {
              padding-left: 10px;
            }
          }
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3 {
          color: $text-hero;
          line-height: 1.13;
        }
        h1 {
          font-weight: 600;
          font-size: clamp(2rem, 5vw, 3.8rem);
          padding-bottom: 30px;
        }
        h2 {
          font-weight: $fw-400;
          font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 1.3rem);
          line-height: 1.5;
          padding-bottom: 30px;
        }
        h3 {
          font-weight: $fw-400;
          font-size: 0.9rem;
        }
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .flexbox {
        .box {
          flex: 1 0 100%;
          .card-wrapper {
            max-width: 440px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am just calling the 'app.scss' file into my main HTML.
This is an image of my file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scss/sass, `@import` and `@use`, they both have the similar purpose. But not the same point. There are some differences between them in whcih,

- `@import` is used for accessing all the `variables` and `mixins` globally.
  It means `@import` load the entire file. It works like a share variable.
- `@use`, on the other hand, is a modular type. It means you have to select
  the specific `variables` or `mixins` and also any specfic `styles` with
  the namespace.
- `@use` is more efficient in which it allows something else features like reducing the risk of conflicting variables.

---

In your code, you shoud have to use like below. As an exmaple,

> _layout.scss

```
$soft-color: #e1e8f0;
$text-hero: white;
$text-white: white;
$card-color: #162c5b;
.......

/** @mixin */
@mixin shadow {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #e8ebf2;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 1px 4px;
}
.......
```

> app.scss

```
@use "layout";
  
.card {
   @include layout.shadow; /** Use @include to load shadow @mixin */
   background: layout.$card-color;
}
```

Use with a namespace: `@use "<url>" as <namespace>`

> app.scss

```
@use "layout" as lt; /** declare a namespace */
    
  .card {
     @include lt.shadow; /** Use @include to load shadow @mixin */
     background: lt.$card-color;
  }
```

---

It's better to read the official documentation. All are mentiond in there.
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/

---

**`a map collection`**

> Your code in the comment

```
$color: ( text: ( 1: #162c5b )); /** This is a nested map */
```

---

> Here an sample is:

```
$colors: (
  primary: (
    background: #3498db,
    text: #e74c3c
  ),
  secondary: (
   ...
  )
);

/** Using the above map collection with map-get */
.primary-text {
   color: map-get(map-get(color.$colors, primary), text);
}

/** Shorthand is a better way. */
.primary-text {
   color: map-get(color.$colors,primary, text); // map-get( $map, $key, $key )
}
```

---

> But, the recommended way, a flexible way:

```
@use "sass:map"; // import at the top of the file you have to use.

.primary-text {
  color: map.get(color.$colors, primary, text);
}

// by this way, map.get(), map.set(), isn't it more flexible and easy to use?
```

Comment: Hello Khant! That is great! but, what about this kind of variable? $color: (
  text: (
    1: #162c5b,)); How do I call it?

Comment: Hello @Luis,
Indeed, it is called `a map collection`.

You can see it like a Javascript Map or Object key-value pair.
You can you the function `map-get( $map, $key);`.  But, a better way is import `@use "sass: map"` at the top. So, this map method can be used with `chain`.
`map.get( $map, $key )`. 

Let revise to my answer above to show with an example.